# Finding Equation of Quadratic When Certain Points Are Known

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

The question is as follows:

Suppose $g(x)$
is a polynomial of degree $5$.
$g(0)=2$
and $g(1)=−623/15$
. Moreover, suppose $g(x)$
has local extreme values at $2√2$,$−2√2$,$√6$
and $√-6$
. Complete this sentence: The formula for this polynomial is $g(x)=$

I can do this quite easily for a quadratic, which is all that we have done so far, however I am not sure how to do this for a fifth degree polynomial. I tried doing it the same way and it became incredibly disorganized, so I'm not sure if that's how you are supposed to do it, or if I am missing something.

Comment: Do you know derivatives? Polynomial has local extrema where its first derivative is zero.

Comment: Yes, this is for my Calculus 1 Course

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** let $g(x)=a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$. Then $$g'(x)=5a_5x^4+4a_4x^3+3a_3x^2+2a_2x+a_1= \\5a_5(x-2\sqrt2)(x+2\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt 6)(x+\sqrt 6) = \\5a_5(x^2-8)(x^2-6)$$ From the equality of polynomials you should be able to create 4 equations for $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. In fact, you can see that $a_4=a_2=0$ right away. The remaining two conditions are to create two more equations.

Comment: I have two questions. First, can you explain how you created the equality of polynomials. And then, can you explain the general thought process on how to solve these sort of problems. I don't need any sort of numbers, just a general way of thinking on how to go about it. My teacher doesn't use any book, so I can't find any explanation.

Comment: @JonahLegg: this is application of the Fundamental theorem of algebra. Simply put, if $x=a$ is a root of polynomial $p(x)$ then $(x-a)$ is a factor of $p(x)$, i.e. $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of one degree lower than $p(x)$